# MySQL join query to create a custom report

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, outer-join

Suppose, I have two table in MySQL Database. First one named `products` and second is `sales`.

Let me keep three different entries for `products` table....

```
+-------+-----------------+-----------+--------+
|id     | productname     | quantity  | uom    |
+-------+-----------------+-----------+--------+
|1      | water bottle    | 20        | piece  |
|2      | cable           | 200       | meter  |
|3      | soap            | 1         | piece  |
+-------+-----------------+-----------+--------+
```

Also I am entering few sales in `sales` table-

```
+-------+---------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
|id     | date                | quantity  | uom    | productid |
+-------+---------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
|1      | 2013-06-21 09:34:00 | 20        | meter  |     2     |
|2      | 2013-06-21 10:35:00 | 100       | meter  |     2     |
|3      | 2013-06-21 11:36:00 | 1         | piece  |     3     |
+-------+---------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

In above `sales` table `productid` is `foreign key`. Every sales entry keeping that `productid`. Now, How to create a report with single entry from left table and multiple entry from right table based on foreign key.

Let me create a mockup of the report-

```
+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+-----------+
| productname     | quantity  | uom    | date                | quantity  |
+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+-----------+
| cable           | 200       | meter  | 2013-06-21 09:34:00 | 20        |
|                 |           |        | 2013-06-21 10:35:00 | 100       |
| soap            | 1         | piece  | 2013-06-21 11:36:00 | 1         |
| water bottle    | 20        | piece  |                     |           |
+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Is it possible to create above reports based on foreign key using MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**  **It's a job for client code that renders your report** from a resultset not for RDBMS.

Use `JOIN` to produce your resultset and then build your report's layout as you wish using client scripting language of your choosing.

If it's php you might find it very handy to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in your query and `explode()` on php side.

```
SELECT p.productname, 
       p.quantity total_quantity, 
       p.uom, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(COALESCE(s.date, ''),'|',COALESCE(s.quantity, '')) ORDER BY s.date) details
  FROM products p LEFT JOIN sales s 
    ON p.id = s.productid
 GROUP BY s.productid, p.productname, p.quantity, p.uom
 ORDER BY p.productname
```

Sample output:

```
|  PRODUCTNAME | TOTAL_QUANTITY |   UOM |                                        DETAILS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        cable |            200 | meter | 2013-06-21 09:34:00|20,2013-06-21 10:35:00|100 |
|         soap |              1 | piece |                          2013-06-21 11:36:00|1 |
| water bottle |             20 | piece |                                              | |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b806/6)** demo.

You php code using PDO might look like

```html
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', 'user', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);


$sql = "SELECT p.productname, 
               p.quantity total_quantity, 
               p.uom, 
               GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(COALESCE(s.date, ''),'|',COALESCE(s.quantity, '')) ORDER BY s.date) details
          FROM products p LEFT JOIN sales s 
            ON p.id = s.productid
         GROUP BY s.productid, p.productname, p.quantity, p.uom
         ORDER BY p.productname";

$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$query = null;
$db = null;
?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Total quantity</th>
            <th>UOM</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo "<tr>
              <td>{$row['productname']}</td>
              <td>{$row['total_quantity']}</td>
              <td>{$row['uom']}</td>";
        $details = explode(',', $row['details']);
        $i = 1;
        foreach($details as $detail) {
            list($date, $quantity) = explode('|', $detail);
            if ($i > 1) {
                echo "<td></td><td></td><td></td>";
            }
            echo "<td>$date</td>
                  <td>$quantity</td></tr>";
            $i++;    
        }
    }
?>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Which will produce the result

```
Product Name  Total quantity  UOM    Date                 Quantity
cable                    120  meter  2013-06-21 09:34:00        20
                                     2013-06-21 10:35:00       100
soap                       1  piece  2013-06-21 11:36:00         1
water bottle              20  piece
```

Comment: I also need to add one more rows which has in `products` table but not yet any sales, Can I add that row with this report?

Comment: @sam See updated answer. The query, sqlfiddle and the query in php code have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

you can have your query with join and group by at the end of query but as i know reply of MySQL queries doesn't return empty fields in rows.

```
    select products.productname , sales.quantity , sales.uom , sales.date , sales.quantity from sales, products where sales.product.id =  products.product.id group by products.productname , sales.date
```

as you see, answer of query will have duplicated productname but with different values in other columns.

Comment: if left table entries will duplicate, then quantity also will duplicate... Am I right? if then, I will not able to figure out the exact summation of `in quantity`.